# average value of transactions per month

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

So, I have multiple orders in a month, and want to find the average value of transactions per month. The code I am using is:

```
# Average value of transactions per month:

trend_month=pd.DataFrame(order_df.groupby('year_month').agg({'order_sum':'mean'}).rename(columns={'order_sum':'mean_transaction'})).reset_index()
x1 = trend_month.year_month.tolist()
y1 = trend_month.mean_transaction.tolist()
mapp = {}
for m,v in zip(x1, y1):
    mapp[m] = v
xn = [calendar.month_abbr[int(x)] for x in sorted(x1)]
vn = [mapp[x] for x in sorted(x1)]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax=sns.barplot(x=xn,y=vn, color='#ed5569')
ax.set_title("Average value of transaction per month")
ax.set_xlabel('Month')
ax.set_ylabel('Value')
```

This outputs an indexerror:
IndexError: list index out of range

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-ce509007ff5a> in <module>
      7 for m,v in zip(x1, y1):
      8     mapp[m] = v
----> 9 xn = [calendar.month_abbr[int(x)] for x in sorted(x1)]
     10 vn = [mapp[x] for x in sorted(x1)]
     11 

<ipython-input-74-ce509007ff5a> in <listcomp>(.0)
      7 for m,v in zip(x1, y1):
      8     mapp[m] = v
----> 9 xn = [calendar.month_abbr[int(x)] for x in sorted(x1)]
     10 vn = [mapp[x] for x in sorted(x1)]
     11 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/calendar.py in __getitem__(self, i)
     57 
     58     def __getitem__(self, i):
---> 59         funcs = self._months[i]
     60         if isinstance(i, slice):
     61             return [f(self.format) for f in funcs]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Do not understand, how/why the list is out of range. Anyone who can see the reason?

Comment: Did you try to print the respective values?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Please provide a [mcve], and see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Hi
The values where printable
No have not debugged but will try now!